# Having trouble printing an array that is within a matrix in python

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix

I am using np.linalg.lstsq to perform a linear least squares problem, which outputs a matrix. I am succesfully getting a matrix, but I am having trouble pulling parts of it out. 
My code is outputting this:

```
b = (matrix([[ -4.86924934e-03],
            [  5.74493035e-03],
            [ -4.54975137e-09],
            [  1.61423505e-09],
            [ -3.62215286e-08],
            [ -1.61423449e-09],
            [ -5.49795983e-05]]), matrix([], shape=(1, 0), dtype=float64), 6, array([  1.79115437e+05,   9.78958908e+04,   6.75604715e+04,
             3.21255052e+01,   3.00000000e+00,   2.99773807e+00,
             3.74438915e-12]))
```

I have named the matrix b, and if I ask to

```html
print b[0][1]
```

I get a print statement of 5.74493035e-03. However I want to get pieces of the array at the end of b. I am trying to use b[1][4] to get the whole array, but so far I am getting an error saying

```html
index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

How can I get to this second array to print pieces of it? What am I doing wrong? Just to be clear, I want the array with a first value of 1.79115437e and a last value of 3.74438915e-12.

Comment: Don't have python available on my phone, but it seems 'b' is a tuple. Try to handle it as one.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code:

```
from numpy import *

b = (matrix([[ -4.86924934e-03],
            [  5.74493035e-03],
            [ -4.54975137e-09],
            [  1.61423505e-09],
            [ -3.62215286e-08],
            [ -1.61423449e-09],
            [ -5.49795983e-05]]),
     matrix([], shape=(1, 0),  dtype=float64),
     6,
     array([  1.79115437e+05,   9.78958908e+04,   6.75604715e+04,3.21255052e+01,   3.00000000e+00,   2.99773807e+00,3.74438915e-12]))
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1580, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 964, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/Users/vafaa/Documents/Pycharm_Projects/test/imsho.py", line 11, in <module>
    matrix([], shape=(1, 0),  dtype=float64),
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shape'
```

by removing the shape():

```
from numpy import *

b = (matrix([[ -4.86924934e-03],
            [  5.74493035e-03],
            [ -4.54975137e-09],
            [  1.61423505e-09],
            [ -3.62215286e-08],
            [ -1.61423449e-09],
            [ -5.49795983e-05]]),
     matrix([],  dtype=float64),
     6,
     array([  1.79115437e+05,   9.78958908e+04,   6.75604715e+04,3.21255052e+01,   3.00000000e+00,   2.99773807e+00,3.74438915e-12]))

print b[3][0], b[3][-1]
```

result:

```
179115.437 3.74438915e-12
```

Seemingly the problem is with the solution of linear least squares problem that you are dealing with.